# When a quasinilpotent is nilpotent?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

In the case of an infinite-dimensional complex banach space $X$,
under what conditions can a quasinilpotent operator $T\in B(X)$ be determined to be nilpotent?

Comment: This is far too vague: it is nilpotent when it is nilpotent. Please try to formulate a more well-defined question, perhaps limiting yourself to certain classes of operators that you are interested in.

Comment: You're right the question lacks some precision: I need to know if there are some "well-known" results giving this implication. Thank you @YemonChoi

Comment: As I am telling you: you seem to be hoping for a magic bullet. Since quasinilpotent operators need not be nilpotent, what kind of conditions are you hoping for? What applications do you have in mind?

Comment: In my research I have a quasinilpotent operator with some particular properties, before using this operator as quasinilpotent, I have to verify if maybe, under the given properties, it is nilpotent, so I asked if there is some well-known results to verify if my operator is nilpotent. For exemple if someone who knows the classical definition of Drazin invertible operators asks if there is well-known results for a Drazin invertible operator to be determined invertible, you can answer him yes you can for exemple verify if its descent equal 0. Thanks @YemonChoi

Comment: "In my research I have a quasinilpotent operator with some particular properties ... I have to verify if maybe, under the given properties, it is nilpotent." So if this operator is given to you, can you not try to check directly if it is nilpotent, rather than trying to find some general theorem?

Comment: OK, let me get the ball rolling. "If T is quasinilpotent and T is idempotent then it is zero, hence it is nilpotent." If this is not satisfactory, could you indicate what kind of answer would be better?

Comment: yes, something like that, but not obvious. I don't know if this operator is nilpotent, I just need to check that this operator is not "obviously" nilpotent, however proving this operator is nilpotent with a complicated proof can be a good deduction then, and the results found can be useful. I'm not familiarized with the notion of quasinilpotent, it's my first use here, that's why I'm asking for help or it will be better to get some good references.

Answer (score 4):

I quasi-nilpotent operator $T \in B(X)$ is nilpotent if and only if $0$ is a pole of its resolvent $(\cdot - T)^{-1}$, which means that there exists a number $M \ge 0$ and an integer $n \ge 1$ such that
$$
  \|(\lambda-T)^{-1}\| \le \frac{M}{\rvert\lambda\lvert^n}
$$
for all $0 \not= \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ close to $0$. This follows from the Laurent series expansion of the resolvent about the point $0$.

Comment: I am confused by this answer. If $T^2 = 0$ then $(\lambda - T)^{-1} = \lambda^{-1} + \lambda^{-2} T$; I don't think it is uniformly bounded above by $M / |\lambda|^n$. Did you may be want the inequality to go the other way? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @WillieWong: Thanks, you're of course right. I wasn't sufficiently careful with the formulation. The estimate needs to be true in a pointed neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for the response @JochenGlueck

Answer (score 2):

This is almost tautological, but suppose that the quasi-nilpotent operator $T$ has the property that, for some $p\in\mathbb N_+$, the equality $\|T^{np}\|=\|T^p\|^n$ holds for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$. Then $0=r(T)=\lim_{n\to0}\|T^{np}\|^{1/np}=\|T^p\|^{1/p},$ so $T^p=0$.

Comment: I'd like to say "quasi-tautoligical"

Comment: thank you for the response